# quickbooks online companyMetaData java

Tags: java, quickbooks

I am trying to access the companyMetaData in quickbooks online using the java api.  I am looking for a means to capture the starting date of the fiscal year.  I have tried to create a new CompaniesMetaDataImpl object with a  new CompaniesMetaDataImpl(context) call.  This does not produce any errors, but also does not generate any company values.  My connection to the qb online company is working, I am just looking for guidance to gain access to these data.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the code that you're trying to use to get the data?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a QBCompanyService, and use that to get the available companies:

```
QBCompanyService db = QBServiceFactory.getService(context, QBCompanyService.class);
CompaniesMetaData comp_mdatas = db.getAvailableCompanies(context);
List<CompanyMetaData> mdatas = comp_mdatas.getCompanyMetaData();
```